# Use title of post as argument for query

Tags: wp-query, get-the-title

I want to use the title of the actual post as argument parameter for a `wp_query`.

I already tried to set it with `the_title` or `get_the_title()` but it does not work. Is it possible to save the title as a string and set it as argument parameter?

```
$arguments = array(
   'tag' => the_title(),
   'cat' => '1'
);
$query = new WP_Query( $arguments );
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
$query->the_post();?>
```

Comment: `the_title` doesn't return the title, it outputs the title. It's the difference between somebody handing you a package, and someone delivering it

Comment: My fault was that my title has spaces in it, but the tag has to be referenced by its slug (hyphens instead of spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You meant to use `get_the_title()` which returns the title as a string. `the_title` instead outputs it to the browser. The same is true of many other functions in WordPress, e.g. `the_post_thumbnail` vs `get_the_post_thumbnail` or `bloginfo` vs `get_bloginfo`

For future reference, a search on https://developer.wordpress.org will usually reveal related functions

Comment: `get_the_title()` is the right method. My fault was something different (title =/= slug)